# How to center right-aligned numbers in table column using CSS?

Tags: html, css

The picture below illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

UPD. As you see, I need the longest number to be centered in its cell, and all other numbers to be right aligned to the longest number's right border.

UPD 2. The numbers are dynamic (unknown initially).

Comment: Is javascript an option?

Comment: I did such thing using JavaScript in one of my projects, but I wanted to know if it's possible to achieve using pure CSS.

Comment: CSS should be enough? You can can have any number of elements embedded inside a td. See my answer...

Comment: Hmm... I think that you would need to use non-breaking spaces to pad the smaller numbers.  So 5 would be something like the following:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5

Comment: @CMKanode That would only work properly with a monospaced font

Comment: What about something like `text-align: right; margin:auto` - would that work?

Comment: @RudiVisser digits are monospaced in every font. You still need a digit-sized space. I think this actually exists.

Comment: @HiveHicks I think adjusting styles with javascript is going to be your best bet. If that's not an option you're going to get some ugly markup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be any direct CSS method. But you could consider the approach suggested by @CMKanode in a comment. You would need to preprocess the numbers in the column and compute the largest of them (this requires locale-sensitive parsing since you are using a thousands separator), and then you would left-pad the numbers to the same number of characters, using U+2007 FIGURE SPACE as a space that has the same width as digits. And, of course, the column would be declared as centered.

So in the example, “5” would be padded to `&#x2007;&nbsp;&#x2007;&#x2007;&#x2007;&nbsp;&#x2007;&#x2007;5` (assuming you use a normal space as thousands separator; U+2009 THIN SPACE might be better, but it has font issues.

The approach would mean that you need to use a font where digits have the same width (most fonts in computers do) and that contains U+2007.

If the thousands separator were a comma or a period, for example, you would need to use U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE in its stead.

In the end, I think this would be excessively complicated. It is probably better to make the column right-aligned but with a suitable left and right padding, selected as a good guess based on the width of the column header and the expected widths of the numbers.

Comment: That sounds interesting, I will give it a try!

Comment: If the table content comes from an outside source, like a SQL query, this solution sounds like a dream. Thanks a lot, Jukka!

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. Using ColdFusion/Java, I generated an array of formatted number strings, passed it to a function that determined max character length (based on number vs punctuation), padded as needed and returned the padded array values. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Below is not an ideal solution, since the size of the numbers are initially unknown, but it's a little closer without too much additional tags.

CSS:

```
.numSpan {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
}
td { text-align: center; }
```

HTML:

```
<td>
    <span class="numSpan">5</span>
</td>
```

Comment: use `width: calc(16% - 5em);` to make it a little bit more responsive.  It's simple but it does exactly what I want on every window size.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me that you need to have a second table inside your main table to determine the width of the numbered content to be centered but right aligned.  Checkout out this fiddle: [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sUZLD/2/)

Example Code:

HTML:

```
<table class="container">
    <tr><td class="title">Some Title for Numbers in a Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>5 000 000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>5 000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>5 000 000</td></tr>
        </table>
   </td></tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #999;    
}

.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;    
}

.container table {
    margin: 0px auto;   
}

.container table td {
    text-align: right;
}​
```

Comment: This breaks the structure of the table and reduces accessibility.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yes, the structure of the table is affected, but seems like it's the only way to do this without JavaScript.

Comment: upvoted! can you do this with a flexbox inside td having 3 cellls

Answer (score 2):

Ok I encountered this problem yesterday , went through all the solutions and came up with my own solution that does not modify the DOM in a significant manner but uses JS but I will list the drawbacks of some of the solutions above

1. Padding extra characters works if your font is monospace
2. Creating a fixed padding or fixed width may affect responsive behavior
3. Adding a second table inside column is serious DOM manipulation, if you have a 1000 rows and 30 columns, you will start seeing the effects of performance with such a heavy tree

**HTML** (Using Bootstrap 4.1.1)

```
<table class="table" id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Symbol</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Volume</th>
      <th>Market Cap</th>
      <th>Circulating Supply</th>
      <th>Total Supply</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.numeric{
  text-align: right;
}


#datatable th, #datatable td{
  text-align: center;
}

.centerspan{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  background: yellow;
}

.root-rank, .root-price, .root-market_cap, .root-max_supply{
  background: #efefef;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var overview_data = [
    { "rank": 1, "symbol": "BTC", "price": 8004.8, "volume_24h": 5864600000000.0, "market_cap": 137422500058.0, "circulating_supply": 17167512.0, "max_supply": 21000000.0},
    { "rank": 2, "symbol": "ETH", "price": 471.305, "volume_24h": 1930260000.0, "market_cap": 47547607782.0, "circulating_supply": 100885006.0, "max_supply": null},
    { "rank": 3, "symbol": "XRP", "price": 0.454852, "volume_24h": 234947000.0, "market_cap": 17882817260.0, "circulating_supply": 39315683476.0, "max_supply": 100000000000.0},
    { "rank": 4, "symbol": "Bitcoin Cash", "price": 845.04, "volume_24h": 730498000.0, "market_cap": 14580563109.0, "circulating_supply": 17254288.0, "max_supply": 21000000.0},
    { "rank": 5, "symbol": "EOS", "price": 8.14097, "volume_24h": 691908000.0, "market_cap": 7295526131.0, "circulating_supply": 896149492.0, "max_supply": 1000000000.0} 
]


var table = document.getElementById("datatable")
var thead = table.tHead
var tbody = table.tBodies[0]
var colClasses = []


for(var i = 0, len= overview_data.length; i < len; i++){
  var tr = document.createElement("tr")
  for(var j in overview_data[i]){
    var td = document.createElement("td")
    td.classList.add("root-" + j)
    var span = document.createElement("span")
    span.classList.add("centerspan")
    span.classList.add('col-' + j)

    //Add this column classes to keep track of one class per column
    if (!colClasses.includes("col-" + j)){
       colClasses.push('col-' + j)
    }
    var text = document.createTextNode(overview_data[i][j] || -1)
    if(!isNaN(overview_data[i][j])){
      td.classList.add("numeric")
    }
    span.appendChild(text)

    td.appendChild(span)
    tr.appendChild(td)
  }
  tbody.appendChild(tr)
}

//This is the main part
for(var i = 0; i < colClasses.length; i++){
  var items = document.querySelectorAll("." + colClasses[i])
  var max = 0

  //Loop through all the items in the col class
  for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
    //Calculate max width of span containing text inside column
    if(items[j].offsetWidth > max){
       max = items[j].offsetWidth
    }
  }

  //Set width of each span to the max width
  for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
    console.log(max)
    items[j].style.width = max + "px"
  }
}
```

**Snapshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a div to td:

```
<td>
    <div align="center">
        <p style="text-align:right">Text Aligned Right</p>
    </div>
</td>
```

Then add padding / margins to fine tune the placement of the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate this with CSS. Create a class:

```
td.rt-ctr {
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:33%;    
}
```

Then call the class in your chart:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td class="rt-ctr">100.25</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td class="rt-ctr">99.75</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Depending upon the width of the column, chart and longest data entry, you may need to adjust the percentage in the CSS. This approach isn't perfect, but it is responsive and is a pure CSS method.

Comment: upvoted! mind adding a small snippet where you actually resize the css padding

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want something like:

```
 .right-td { align:right; }
```

going with

```
<td class="right-td">5000000</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual `td` in that `table` (if it is indeed a table) will have a fixed width, and lots of padding to give the illusion that it's centre-right-aligned.

You could try a crude style such as this:

```
/* For demonstration purposes, a fixed width `th`. */
th.headrowrnum {
    width: 200px;
}

td.rightalignnum {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 50px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th class="headrowrnum">Col 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>X</td>
        <td class="rightalignnum">5</td>
    </tr>>
    <tr>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td class="rightalignnum">500</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that alignment, you should do something like this:

HTML:

```
<td class="my_td">
    <div class="content">
        12345
    </div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.my_td 
{
    width: 200px;
    align: center;
}

.content
{
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: right;
}
```

You just need to adapt the widths to meet your requirements, for instance, max digits in the number.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use media queries.  In our case, we have roughly the same number of columns in every table.  So, just change the right padding based on screen size to give the desired right/center alignment:

```
@media (min-width: 769px)
{
   td
   {
      &.financial
      {
         padding-right: 5px;
      }
   }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px)
{
   td
   {
      &.financial
      {
         padding-right: 20px;
      }
   }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px)
{
   td
   {
      &.financial
      {
         padding-right: 30px;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -7):

In CSS, do this to center-align td

```
td {text-align:center;}
```

Comment: No. The cells appear to need to be right aligned to a central area.

Comment: This doesn't seem to achieve what is displayed on the screenshot.

Comment: I know how to center stuff, but how to keep the right aligned to each other while centering in cell.